# Concatenate arrays of subclasses of the same superclass in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, casting, oop

I have the following structure in matlab

```
superClass < handle

subClassA < superClass

subClassB < superClass
```

say I have a vector A of subClassA and a vector B of subClassB.

I would like to combine them like this:

```
superVector = [A B];
```

but Matlab doesn't like this.  What's the proper way to cast the subclass back to the superclass?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nevermind - it's impossible

[matlab oop help](http://www.mathworks.es/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/matlab_oop/brglmxp.html)

MATLAB does not allow you to create arrays containing a mix of superclass and subclass objects because an array can be of only one class. If you attempt to concatenate objects of different classes, MATLAB looks for a converter method defined by the less dominant class (generally, the left-most object in the expression is the dominant class).

Comment: BTW: I think my workaround is going to be to use cells instead.

Comment: I wouldn't say it's *impossible*. It simply requires that you have the ability to convert one subclass to the other using a [converter method](http://www.mathworks.es/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/matlab_oop/br2vkky.html). The drawback is that you don't always want to do that for fear of losing properties specific to the unconverted object. In addition, you can also specify the [precedence of classes](http://www.mathworks.es/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/matlab_oop/brf5okb-1.html) to control which one gets converted to the other.

Comment: Well no, it's still impossible.  Say my super class is Shape, my subclasses are Square and Circle, and Shape defines but does not implement an area method.  If I wanted to make an array of Circles and Squares, then sort them by area, I couldn't convert them to Shapes, because in order to compute the area, the object needs to know if it's a square or a circle.  The same problem applies to any overridden method.

Comment: I was actually speaking in a more general sense of combining two different classes into an array. For example, if you had a converter method that changed a Square into a Circle, you could combine Squares and Circles in an array. However, this is not a conversion you would necessarily *want* or *be able* to make in many cases, like in the specific example you gave. Alternatively, consider a superclass Person with subclasses Employee and Friend. You could have a converter method that changes the Employee class to a Friend class, allowing concatenation of Employee and Friend objects.

Comment: @gnovice: sorry missed the line "The drawback is that you don't always want to do that for fear of losing properties specific to the unconverted object".  Still this is a major difference between MATLAB oop and C++ or java, & imho, it really weakens MATLAB to do it this way.  At the very least, they should allow arrays of handles of arbitrary type.
---
In your example, I might want to make a list of all people, both employees and friends, without losing track of whether someone is an employee or a friend, which is trivial in other languages, but impossible in MATLAB.

Answer (score 4):

cat

Class: matlab.mixin.Heterogeneous
Package: matlab.mixin

Concatenation for heterogeneous arrays

this solves your problem...old post, i know